# Installing MySQL 5.6 on Amazon EC2 AMI

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I need to install MySQL 5.6 (this very version) on my Amazon EC2 AMI but I can't find a way.

The version currently installed is this one:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

And if I go to the MySQL website, I can find only the version 5.5.25:
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Would you know how to install it?

And if I can't yet, where can I find how long I need to wait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [Mysql's download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and click on the Development releases tab at the bottom. You'll find 5.6 there.